# Gaussian Blur - black and white image turns to red and orange

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera

I was expecting that the output should still be black and white(image after applying grayscale) but with blur effect..I'm stuck with red-orange image right now... any suggestions?

```
    public void applyGaussianBlur(int[][] rgb){
    int kernelWidth = 3, kernelHeight = 3;

    float kernel[][] = new float[kernelWidth][kernelHeight];
    float sigma = 3.5f, radius = 1.0f;
    float sum = 0;


    for(int x = 0; x < kernelWidth;x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < kernelHeight; y++){
            kernel[x][y] = (float)((1/(2*radius*sigma*sigma)) * Math.exp((-(x*x+y*y))/(2*sigma*sigma)));
            sum+=kernel[x][y];
        }
    }


    for (int j = 1; j < width-1; j++){
        for (int m = 1; m < height-1;m++){
            sum += (rgb[j-1][m-1] * kernel[0][2]);
            sum += (rgb[j-1][m] * kernel[0][1]);
            sum += (rgb[j-1][m+1] * kernel[0][0]);

            sum += (rgb[j][m-1] * kernel[1][2]);
            sum += (rgb[j][m] * kernel[1][1]);
            sum += (rgb[j][m+1] * kernel[1][0]);

            sum += (rgb[j+1][m-1] * kernel[2][2]);
            sum += (rgb[j+1][m] * kernel[2][1]);
            sum += (rgb[j+1][m+1] * kernel[2][0]);

            rgb[j][m] = Math.round(sum/9);
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: instead of using a nested loop (very slow!!), use a ColorMatrix (really fast!!) to get your effect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. i'm gonna try it now :)

Comment: Or you can use this [super-fast technique](http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/)